# grails 3.2.1 jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, grails

i'm new to grails and i have installed grails 3.2.1 in my system. i currently trying to install the jquery ui plugin
i followed the instruction given from the grails document. i have attached the link below.
https://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui
finally i have found that "grails install-plugin" is depricated.
thing is i'm new to the grails 3 environment and i need a step by step instruction to install jquery ui.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's the old Grails 2 plugin; there isn't and won't be a Grails 3+ plugin for jQuery or jQueryUI because there wasn't much value in using the plugins in Grails 2. Just do what you would do in any application - download whatever JavaScript, CSS, images, fonts, etc. you need to work with them directly.

Add them to the `grails-app/assets` folders and be sure to read the [asset-pipeline plugin docs](http://asset-pipeline.com/manual/index.html) for information about packaging, bundling, minification, etc.